# Cannot connect to postgres cloudsql from app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am making my first app engine project using `Go`. I have a cloud sql instance and app engine in the same project inside cloud console.

I have the following inside my `app.yaml` file:

```
service: myservice
runtime: go
api_version: go1

env_variables:
  #for deploying
  #POSTGRES_CONNECTION: "user=postgres password=<redacted> dbname=my_database host=/cloudsql/myproject:us-west1:myserver"

  #for testing locally via cloud proxy
  POSTGRES_CONNECTION: "user=postgres password=<redacted> dbname=mydatabase sslmode=disable"


beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: myproject:us-west1:myserver

handlers:

# All URLs are handled by the Go application script
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

In the code I open the connection like this:

```
datastoreName := os.Getenv("POSTGRES_CONNECTION")
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", datastoreName)
```

On my local machine I have setup `cloud_sql_proxy` like this:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=passio-nutrition-develop-bcb6:us-west1:nutrition-sqlite-source=tcp:5432
```

And with `POSTGRES_CONNECTION` set up for local testing, everything works perfectly well.

However, when I set `POSTGRES_CONNECTION` for deploying, and run `gcloud app deploy`, I get an error message when I attempt to hit an endpoint:

```
{"Op":"dial","Net":"unix","Source":null,"Addr":{"Name":"/cloudsql/myproject:us-west1:myserver/.s.PGSQL.5432","Net":"unix"},"Err":{"Syscall":"socket","Err":1}}
```

I have tried various different versions of `POSTGRES_CONNECTION`, including adding `=tcp:5432` to the end of the `host` and `cloud_sql_instances`, but I cannot get the connection to work.

If anyone could give me some pointers that would be great

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Cloud SQL Admin API enabled, and that your default App Engine service account has the correct IAM permissions (it needs to have the `Cloud SQL Connect` role or higher).

Answer (score 0):

Example of a app.yaml

runtime: go

api_version: go1

handlers:

url: /stylesheets

static_dir: stylesheets

url: /(.*.(gif|png|jpg))$

static_files: static/\1

upload: static/.*.(gif|png|jpg)$

url: /.*

script: _go_app

Connecting to Postgresql

package main

import (

"database/sql"

"fmt"

_ "github.com/lib/pq"

)

const (

host     = "localhost"

port     = 5432

user     = "postgres"

password = "your-password"

dbname   = "calhounio_demo"

)

func main() {

psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+

```
"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",

host, port, user, password, dbname)
```

db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)

if err != nil {

```
panic(err)
```

}

defer db.Close()

err = db.Ping()

if err != nil {

```
panic(err)
```

}

fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")

}